# Configure MariaDB to log row deletion ONLY

Tags: trigger, mariadb, delete, log

I'm investigating some rows/tables that intermittently go missing on a Magento site, and of course there's no entries in the error log. (I suspect Magento queries/rules or human error might be the culprit) I know I can enable the General log, but I don't want to log EVERYTHING as this site processes a huge amount of sales every day and the log would be massive.

I'm hoping someone might know of a way to configure either the general log or log table to record only `DELETE` commands. Open to any suggestions you might have of a better way to go about this.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for the quick response. To clarify, the Magento admins have stated that an entire category of products "goes missing", I highly doubt the table itself is dropped as they've been able to import the missing products from a backup without too much difficulty.

As far as a trigger after a `DELETE` is concerned, I assume something like an `INSERT INTO delete_log` would do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly copied from [the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/trigger-examples/):

**Trigger Example - Logging deletions**

> Scenario: We want to keep a log file containing data from rows that have been deleted from the BOOKS Table. Here's a Trigger definition that accomplishes this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Books_Delete
AFTER DELETE ON Books                 /* See note 1 */
  REFERENCING OLD ROW AS Old          /* See note 2 */
FOR EACH ROW                          /* See note 3 */
  INSERT INTO Books_Deleted_Log       /* See note 4 */
      VALUES (Old.title);             /* See note 5 */
```

1. The Trigger action has to be **AFTER**, since the Trigger action includes a SQL-data change statement. You should also replace `Books` with your table name
2. It is conventional to use the alias "Old" or "Old_Row" for the old row.
3. No log will occur for a `DELETE` statement that affects zero rows.
4. Replace `Books_Deleted_Log` with the name of the table you're logging the deleted rows into. Make sure this table has all the columns you need to log the information you need.
5. `OLD` is an alias for a single old row, so `OLD.TITLE` is the scalar value derived from the `TITLE` Column of that old row. You will have to change `Title` to a column you want to track. You can also add more columns by following the `Old.<column name>` pattern using commas as separators.

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Thanks so much for your help, @Erik. I love this community.

Comment: @Powelly sure thing. Glad I could help.